# How to call web service from excel Macro

Tags: web-services, excel, excel-2003, vba

I need to call an webservice method from my excel macro. can any on suggest me how can i do that. I don't want to use soap related thing durin calling the webservice in macro code.

Thanks in advance.

Eshwer Nayudu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wish to use the SOAP type library, you could use MSXML instead and create the SOAP request manually in code and then post it to the web service.

Please take a look at http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=7611 for a nice example. It's for VB6, but I am sure it would need little adjustment for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a simple class which acts as a WCF client to the service. Then, with just a little more work, you can turn this class into a COM object. Excel can easily access COM objects.